# После билда игра работает нормально,но в unity нет

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть у меня кнопка которая после нажатия должна менять цвет.
В Unity она не работает , но после билда на телефон все работает корректно.
Есть какие-либо предположения ?
Код:

```
switch (BackgroundMemory)
{
        case 4:
            if (MoneyInShop >= 0)
            {
                if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("SkinB4"))
                {
                    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SkinB4") == 1)
                    {
                        BackgroundSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = SpriteB4;
                        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayerDecisionBackground", 4);

                    }
                    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SkinB4") == 0)
                    {

                        if (MoneyInShop >= 0)
                        {
                            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayerDecisionBackground", 4);
                            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SkinB2", 1);
                            BackgroundSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = SpriteB4;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (MoneyInShop >= 0)
                    {
                        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayerDecisionBackground", 4);
                        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SkinB4", 1);
                        BackgroundSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = SpriteB4;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log("You haven't money");
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

}
```

После делаю проверку (запускаю метод) :

```
 if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("SkinB4"))
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SkinB4") == 1)
        {
            ButtonChangeB4.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = GreenButton;
            Destroy(TextBackground3);
        }
    }
```

---

В игре `MoneyInShop` больше 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему получилась такая проблема я так и не смог разобраться , но решил удалить все `PlayerPrefs`

```
PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
```

После данного действия все заработало как нужно.

Comment: это говорит о том, что скорее всего Вы рефакторили код, связанные с PlayerPrefs и наткнулись на старые ключи-значения, на которых Ваша логика падала, надо всегда держать в голове, что в PlayerPrefs могут быть данные от старых версий вашего ПО